# Select fields of a table with a conditional WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, conditional-statements

I have 3 left joined tables in MySql.

`contratos`, which stores customer data

`funcionario`, which stores employee data

`cobranca`, which stores every customer charge.

I want to generate a report based on charge `status`. But each customer charge has many `status`, and i want to retrieve the current `status`.

The following code returns the last update from `cobrancas` table.

```
SELECT cob.status, cob.created, con.data_venda, cpn.contrato, con.razao_social, con.cnpj, con.valor, f.nick
FROM cobrancas cob
LEFT JOIN contratos con
ON c.id = cob.contrato
LEFT JOIN funcionarios f
ON f.id = cob.cobrador
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY cob.created DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But it returns without a `status` filter. If i put a WHERE clause like `cob.status = 'x'`, it returns the last record with this `status`, but it may not be the current. So how can i check if `cob.status` is the current `status` in WHERE clause to decide if i will put it in the list? Something like:

`WHERE IF(cob.status == the last status inserted AND cob.status == 'x')`

Can you understand what i want to do? Thank you.

Comment: How do you decide which the current status is?

Comment: I use **ORDER BY DESC** and **LIMIT 1** in the first query. But i don't know how to do this in Where clause. I have a **created** field which stores the date and hour.

Comment: And where's your problem then, if it works?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to use subquery

```
select * from
(
SELECT cob.status, cob.created, con.data_venda, cpn.contrato, con.razao_social, con.cnpj, con.valor, f.nick
FROM cobrancas cob
LEFT JOIN contratos con
ON c.id = cob.contrato
LEFT JOIN funcionarios f
ON f.id = cob.cobrador
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY cob.created DESC
LIMIT 1
) where status = 'X'
```

Comment: and join other 2 tables to outer query, it will be faster